# Replace select with an input, in table row

Tags: javascript, html

I tried the script found here, it can run only on the first row, if add the second row and the next row, the javascript function can't run.

this is my code:

```js
function addRow() {
  var x = document.getElementById('bon').rows.length-1;
  
  var table = document.getElementById('bon').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
  var row = table.insertRow(-1);
  
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
  var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
  var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
  
  cell1.innerHTML = '<button tabindex="-1" type="button" class="btn red" onclick="javascript:deleteRow('+x+');">'+x+'</button>';
  cell2.innerHTML = '<div class="form-group form-md-line-input"> <select class="form-control kdbng1" name="kdbng1[]" required=""> <?php while($data31=mysqli_fetch_array($tb31)){ ?> <option value="<?php echo $data31['tpbenang'] ?>"><?php echo $data31['tpbenang']?></option> <?php } ?> </select></div>';
  cell3.innerHTML = '<div class="form-group form-md-line-input"> <select class="form-control kdbng2" name="kdbng2[]" required=""> <option value="0">-</option> <?php while($data32=mysqli_fetch_array($tb32)){ ?> <option value="<?php echo $data32['tpbenang'] ?>"><?php echo $data32['tpbenang']?></option> <?php } ?> </select></div>';
  cell4.innerHTML = '<div class="form-group form-md-line-input"> <select class="form-control kdbng3" name="kdbng3[]" required=""> <option value="0">-</option> <?php while($data33=mysqli_fetch_array($tb33)){ ?> <option value="<?php echo $data33['tpbenang'] ?>"><?php echo $data33['tpbenang']?></option> <?php } ?> </select></div>';
  cell5.innerHTML = '<div class="form-group form-md-line-input"> <select class="form-control wrnbng" name="wrnbng[]" id="mylist" required=""> <option value="">- Pilih Warna Benang -</option> <?php while($data4=mysqli_fetch_array($tb2)){ ?> <option value="<?php echo $data4['wrbenang'] ?>"><?php echo $data4['wrbenang']?></option> <?php } ?> </select></div>';
  
  $('.kdbng').typeahead('destroy');
  $('.kdbng').typeahead({
    highlight: true
  }, {
    name: 'kdbngs',
    displayKey: 'kd_benang',
    source: kdbngs.ttAdapter()
  })
  window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);

  setAttributes();
}
```

This is the javascript code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mylist').change(function() {
    if (this.value == 'Lainnya') {
      $('#mylist').replaceWith('<input class="form-control wrnbng" name="wrnbng[]" required="" placeholder="Masukan Nama & Kode Benang">');
    }
  });
});
```

How do make the javascript function also run on the next row?
Thanks

Comment: What errors do you get when you attempt running this?

Comment: The replace in row 1 is work. But, when I add second row, the replace doesnt run

Comment: I need to see what error message you are getting.

Comment: this the error https://www.veed.io/view/b1ba064e-3c24-43e5-86b1-a0251725a11a?panel=share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("#mylist").change` is attached only once when `$(document).ready`.
When you add the new row in `cell5.innerHTML` you have to attach a new event to it.

```js
function onMyListChangeHandler(element){
  if(element.value == "value2"){
    const input = document.createElement("input");
    input.placeholder = "type...";
    element.replaceWith(input);
  }
}

function addRow(){
  const table = document.querySelector('#myTable tbody');
  
  const row = table.insertRow(-1);
  
  const cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  const cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  
  const countRows = table.querySelectorAll('tr').length - 1;
  cell1.textContent = 'test row ' + countRows;
  cell2.innerHTML = `
      <select onchange="onMyListChangeHandler(this)">
        <option value="value1">value 1</option>
        <option value="value2">value 2</option>
      </select>
  `;

}
```

```html
<button onclick="addRow()">Add row</button>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>column 1</th>
    <th>column 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test row 1</td>
    <td>
      <select onchange="onMyListChangeHandler(this)">
        <option value="value1">value 1</option>
        <option value="value2">value 2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I've changed the code to keep it simple. Instead of attaching the event, it is added within the element creation.

You can run the snippet to test it.

Comment: this work only if the first row replaced with input / click "Lainnya". If first row with dropdown value, and second row want to replace with input, it cant be done

Comment: Sorry. onchange was the event I was intended to use. I will update it.

Comment: and now, the dropdown not replaced

Comment: Because probably you still doing this: $('#mylist').replaceWith(...

Comment: That will replace the first element with that id (id should be unique) I don't recommend using jQuery at all. But passing a ref of the element should make ir work.

Comment: Editing again to add that change

Comment: still not work sir, please help

Comment: fully updated as a simpler version